# Firemonkey app fail when calling FreeLibrary

Tags: delphi, dll, firemonkey

I have a simple Firemonkey app, that loads a DLL, call a procedure within that DLL, which just calls ShowMessage('Dialog from DLL ...'); and returns
That all OK, but the calling application fails, when FreeLibrary has been called and I try closing the main app ?

If I leave out the FreeLibrary call, the application closes without error.

Anybody seen this before, and why ?

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but Delphi 10 Seattle also fails on Windows 7.

The application code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  Winapi.Windows;
type
  TTest = procedure (); stdcall;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LibHandle: NativeUInt;
  Test: TTest;
begin
  LibHandle:= LoadLibrary('.\TESTDLL.DLL');
  if LibHandle > 32 then try
    @Test:= GetProcAddress(LibHandle, 'Test');
    if @Test <> nil then
      Test;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(LibHandle);
  end;
end;
```

And the DLL code:

```
library TESTDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  FMX.Dialogs
  ;

{$R *.res}

procedure Test; stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage('Dialog from DLL ...');
end;

exports
  Test name 'Test';

begin
end.
```

If the dll procedure don't contain any calls related to display things, the app behaves as expected.
Any hints help or suggestions, greatly appreciated.

Edit: Included the complete code from main app.

Comment: The first uses in any library should be `sharemem`. And you have not shown us all the relevant code. Narrow down the code to a MCVE and get back to us.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Johan That is incorrect. `sharemem` is optional, only needed if you want to actually utilize it. I personally never use it, as I want my DLLs to be self-contained and able to use from other languages. The above code looks like an MCVE too. What code is missing?

Comment: But without sharemem how is `any calls related to display things` going to work? Passing parameters like strings is going to fail real soon. The above code does not give any error and it is inconsistent with the OP's description of the problem.

Comment: @Johan Always worked fine for me. I've even embedded a form from a Delphi DLL into a C# application, in which case `sharemem` would be useless.

Comment: @Johan. Never used sharemem in any library, because I've always used PChar in my calls to a DLL if I needed a string. The code is copy/paste exactly as compiled and run. BTW the code also fails if calling from a VCL app.